# Using Failsafe-Plugin, I can't execute my tests in parallel mode

Tags: java, selenium, maven

Using Failsafe-Plugin, I can't execute my tests in parallel mode.
My execution is well but only in one thread.

Here is my pom.xml

Properties :

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <junit.version>5.8.2</junit.version>
        <cucumber.version>7.3.4</cucumber.version>

        <!--<maven.compiler.version>3.10.1</maven.compiler.version>-->
        <maven.compiler.version>3.10.1</maven.compiler.version>

        <maven.surefire.version>3.0.0-M3</maven.surefire.version>
        <maven.failsafe.plugin>3.0.0-M3</maven.failsafe.plugin>
    </properties>
```

Dependencies :

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/tech.grasshopper/extentreports-cucumber7-adapter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber7-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Plugins :

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            <source>${java.version}</source>
            <target>${java.version}</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.failsafe.plugin}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>

                    <!-- UNCOMMENT - To add any exclusions if required-->
                    <!-- <excludes><exclude>**/*IT*.java</exclude></excludes>-->

                    <includes>

                        <!-- UNCOMMENT BELOW LINE - To execute feature files with a single runner-->
                        <include>**/MyTestRunner.java</include>

                        <!-- UNCOMMENT BELOW LINE - To execute feature files with multiple runners-->
                        <!-- <include>**/*Runner.java</include>-->
                    </includes>

                    <!-- UNCOMMENT BELOW 3 LINES - To execute using parallel or combination option-->
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                    <threadCount>4</threadCount>
                    <perCoreThreadCount>true</perCoreThreadCount>
                    

                    <!-- UNCOMMENT BELOW 3 LINES - To execute using forking or combination option -->
                    <!-- <forkCount>2</forkCount> <reuseForks>true</reuseForks> <reportsDirectoty>${project-->
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

</plugins>
```

I use also :
junit-jupiter-api 5.8.2,
selenium-java 4.2.2,
cucumber-java and cucumber-junit 7.3.4,
maven-compiler-plugin 3.10.1,
maven-surfire-plugin 3.0.0-M3

I tried to change some versions, erase testng from eclipse without results.

Comment: First upgrade maven-failsafe-plugin to most recent version ... 3.0.0-M7...please also add the full pom file... because I'm reading something about TestNG?? And JUnit Jupiter? Do you use both frameworks ?

Comment: That's works, with 3.0.0-M3 version of failsafe and surefire and by executing in a console (mvn verify).
But, that doesn't work with 3.0.0-M7 version of surefire and failsafe
Thank you all, thank you @khmarbaise